# react native ios QRCodeScanner error ( camera not authorized )

Tags: react-native, qr-code, react-native-camera

I'm using
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-camera": "^3.37.0",

'camera not authorized' is the error displayed when the camera is launched

same is true with different camera libraries, but default camera works normally

I've added:

{
NSCameraUsageDescription
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription
}
to ios/project/Info.plist

and also tried:

cameraProps={{captureAudio: false}}

but its not working. Any insights will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are you testing it on an IOS emulator or a physical device(iPhone)? Is it an expo wrapped app or is it RN? Have you asked for camera permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me.

I noted that in one place I have check platform condition using single equal operator by mistake like

```
paddingTop: (Platform.OS = 'android'
                  ? 16
                  : 4)
```

then after changed it to  (replacing single equal with double equal while platform condition matching)

```
   paddingTop: (Platform.OS == 'android'
                      ? 16)

                  : 4)
```